# Why is serde always std-gated in substrate?

Tags: wasm, no-std

I regularly see `serde` implemented for various structs across the substrate ecosystem, usually in the single-liner form below. Why is that gated behind the std feature? In serde's [documentation](https://serde.rs/no-std.html), it's clear that there is full support for a `no-std` environment, including derivations. What's the reason for gating it behind the `std` feature? Is it only for binary size / WASM blob size reasons?

```rust
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to acknowledge the `std` feature flag in Substrate is very imperfect. It represents both a separation of `std` from `no_std`, but it also USUALLY implies `wasm`. It has been noted before that with hindsight, we would have explicitly made a `wasm` or `runtime` feature flag, rather than jumping on top of `no_std`. That being said, wherever `no_std` shows up, we must pretty much assume it is Wasm.

Going back to the question, AFAIK it is very much about both the Wasm size, and the fact that `serde` itself should never really leak into the runtime.

The runtime should only need to speak in SCALE.

`serde` is only used in specific situations on the client side, for example to parse JSON for the `genesis_config` / `chain_spec`. This can leak into the runtime, where some runtime struct is getting exposed to the client and through some non-SCALE interface, and therefore a struct would need to implement `serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}`, feature gated by `std`.

That being said, you could bring in `serde` with `no_std` into your runtime / pallet if you wanted. For example, if you explicitly wanted to parse a JSON file through an extrinsic, this should all be doable, however this is probably not even the best option. There are libraries like [`lite-json`](https://github.com/xlc/lite-json) written by our community to be extremely lightweight in the runtime, or even better use SCALE in the first place.

So in summary, yes Wasm blob size is one reason, but perhaps even more concretely, there shouldn't be need for `serde` in the runtime, as you have `SCALE`, therefore, we always feature gate it.